# Cannot access pod via pod IP from within the cluster, causing liveness / readiness probe failure

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

**Some quick background:** creating an app in golang, running on minikube on MacOS 10.14.2

```
karlewr [0] $ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.1", GitCommit:"b1b29978270dc22fecc592ac55d903350454310a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-07-18T11:37:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.4", GitCommit:"f49fa022dbe63faafd0da106ef7e05a29721d3f1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-14T06:59:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**The Issue:**
I cannot access my pod via it's pod IP from inside my cluster. This problem is only happening with this one pod which leads me to believe I have a misconfiguration somewhere.

My pods spec is as follows:

```
containers:
  - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
    image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
    ports:
      - name: http
        containerPort: 8080
        protocol: TCP
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /ping
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 60
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /ping
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 60
```

What's weird is that I can access it by port-forwarding that pod on port `8080` and running `curl localhost:8080/ping` before the liveness and readiness probes run and after the pod has been initialized. This returns 200 OK.

Also during this time before `CrashLoopBackoff`, if I ssh into my minikube node and run `curl http://172.17.0.21:8080/ping` I get `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.21 port 8080: Connection refused`. The IP used is my pod's IP.

But then when I describe the pod after the `initialDelaySeconds` period, I see this:

```
  Warning  Unhealthy  44s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet, minikube  Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.21:8080/ping: dial tcp 172.17.0.21:8080: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  44s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet, minikube  Liveness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.21:8080/ping: dial tcp 172.17.0.21:8080: connect: connection refused
```

Why would my connection be getting refused only from the pod's IP?

**Edit** I am not running any custom networking things, just minikube out of the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why would my connection be getting refused only from the pod's IP?

Because your program is apparently only listening on localhost (aka `127.0.0.1` aka `lo0`)

Without knowing more about your container we can't advise you further, but that's almost certainly the problem based on your description.

Comment: This was it. Thank you for your input. It's very appreciated!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, and I'm glad to have contributed to your experience on SO. Please mark my answer as accepted, so others can see the solution